# Three.JS Cannot change HDR RGBELoader Offset.y Value

Tags: three.js

I have an object which when a normal texture is applied allows me to change the offset.y value, however when using RGBELoader and a HDR file I can no longer change the offset.y.

My code is as follows:

```
                var loader3 = new THREE.ObjectLoader();
            loader3.load("model/dome/dome2.json",function ( obj ) {
                obj.scale.x = 7;
                obj.scale.y = 7;
                obj.scale.z = 7;
                obj.position.x = 0;
                obj.position.z = 0;
                obj.position.y = 0;


                var loader = new THREE.RGBELoader();
                var texture = loader.load( "maps/scene2.hdr", function( texture, textureData ){
                    materialHDR = new THREE.ShaderMaterial( {
                        uniforms: {
                            tDiffuse:  { type: "t", value: texture },
                            exposure:  { type: "f", value: textureData.exposure },
                            brightMax: { type: "f", value: textureData.gamma }
                            },
                        vertexShader: getText( 'vs-hdr' ),
                        fragmentShader: getText( 'fs-hdr' )
                    } );


                    texture.offset.y = 0.5; // HERE LIES THE PROBLEM
                    texture.flipY = true;

                    obj.traverse( function ( child ) {
                        if ( child instanceof THREE.Mesh ) {
                            child.material = materialHDR;
                            child.receiveShadow = true;
                            //child.material.side = THREE.BackSide;
                            child.material.side = THREE.DoubleSide;
                        }
                    });

                    scene.add( obj );
                } );


            });
```

The HDR image loads just fine and is applied to the object just as it is when I use a normal texture however I just cannot move the texture around the model at all.

I have tried wrap with repeat and all sorts of combinations but the stubborn offset will not work!

I would also like to add I am currently learning three.js (awesome!) so excuse the code above if it has any additional errors.

Thanks for any help in advance it is driving me nuts!

Shader code below

```
        <script id="fs-hdr" type="x-shader/x-fragment">
        uniform sampler2D   tDiffuse;
        uniform float       exposure;
        uniform float       brightMax;
        varying vec2  vUv;
        vec3 decode_pnghdr( const in vec4 color ) {
            vec4 rgbcolor = vec4( 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0 );
            if ( color.w > 0.0 ) {
                float f = pow(2.0, 127.0*(color.w-0.5));
                rgbcolor.xyz = color.xyz * f;
            }
            return rgbcolor.xyz;
            /*
            // remove gamma correction
            vec4 res = color * color;
            // decoded RI
            float ri = pow( 2.0, res.w * 32.0 - 16.0 );
            // decoded HDR pixel
            res.xyz = res.xyz * ri;
            return res.xyz;
            */
        }
        void main() {
            vec4 color = texture2D( tDiffuse, vUv );
            color.xyz  = decode_pnghdr( color );
            // apply gamma correction and exposure
            //gl_FragColor = vec4( pow( exposure * color.xyz, vec3( 0.474 ) ), 1.0 );
            // Perform tone-mapping
            float Y = dot(vec4(0.30, 0.59, 0.11, 0.0), color);
            float YD = exposure * (exposure/brightMax + 1.0) / (exposure + 1.0);
            color *= YD;
            gl_FragColor = vec4( color.xyz, 1.0 );
        }
    </script>

    <!-- HDR vertex shader -->

    <script id="vs-hdr" type="x-shader/x-vertex">
        varying vec2 vUv;
        void main() {
            vUv  = uv;
            gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4( position, 3 );
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: Can you show your shader code?

Comment: sure shader code above thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your custom shader must handle the `offset/repeat`.

Add `offsetRepeat` to your uniforms;

```
offsetRepeat: { type: "v4", value: new THREE.Vector4( 0, 0.5, 1, 1 ) }
```

And modify your vertex shader

```
uniform vec4 offsetRepeat;
varying vec2 vUv;

void main() {

    vUv = uv * offsetRepeat.zw + offsetRepeat.xy;

    gl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 );

}
```

Your texture must be power-of-two, and set

```
texture.wrapS = texture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
```

three.js r.75

Comment: WestLangley... you sir are a modern day genius, thank you for your help thats a 4 hour headache over I will now retire to my fridge for a cold beverage :)